# Blazor and Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, blazor

I'm working on a project using Entity Framework and Blazor. First I created my tables in the database, but later I realised that I needed more tables. I added these tables, however an error appears when I try to add a migration:

[image: Error]

Comment: Where have you added the tables? in code or database?

Comment: Did you *read* the message? It says to use `EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration`

Comment: i got the problem by using the command line

Answer (score 1):

first remove EntityFramework package:

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework
```

then install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` from nugget and add `EntityFrameworkCore\` before `Add-Migrationtry`:

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration
```